# Using Iteratees and Enumerators in Play Scala to Stream Data to S3

Tags: scala, playframework, amazon-s3, loops

I am building a Play Framework application in Scala where I would like to stream an array of bytes to S3. I am using the [Play-S3](https://github.com/Rhinofly/play-s3) library to do this. The "Multipart file upload" of the documentation section is what's relevant here:

```
// Retrieve an upload ticket
val result:Future[BucketFileUploadTicket] =
  bucket initiateMultipartUpload BucketFile(fileName, mimeType)

// Upload the parts and save the tickets
val result:Future[BucketFilePartUploadTicket] =
  bucket uploadPart (uploadTicket, BucketFilePart(partNumber, content))

// Complete the upload using both the upload ticket and the part upload tickets
val result:Future[Unit] =
  bucket completeMultipartUpload (uploadTicket, partUploadTickets)
```

I am trying to do the same thing in my application but with `Iteratee`s and `Enumerator`s.

The streams and asynchronicity make things a little complicated, but here is what I have so far (Note `uploadTicket` is defined earlier in the code):

```
val partNumberStream = Stream.iterate(1)(_ + 1).iterator
val partUploadTicketsIteratee = Iteratee.fold[Array[Byte], Future[Vector[BucketFilePartUploadTicket]]](Future.successful(Vector.empty[BucketFilePartUploadTicket])) { (partUploadTickets, bytes) =>
  bucket.uploadPart(uploadTicket, BucketFilePart(partNumberStream.next(), bytes)).flatMap(partUploadTicket => partUploadTickets.map( _ :+ partUploadTicket))
}
(body |>>> partUploadTicketsIteratee).andThen {
  case result =>
    result.map(_.map(partUploadTickets => bucket.completeMultipartUpload(uploadTicket, partUploadTickets))) match {
      case Success(x) => x.map(d => println("Success"))
      case Failure(t) => throw t
    }
}
```

Everything compiles and runs without incident. In fact, `"Success"` gets printed, but no file ever shows up on S3.

Answer (score 6):

There might be multiple problems with your code. It's a bit unreadable caused by the `map` method calls. You might have a problem with your future composition. Another problem might be caused by the fact that all chunks (except for the last) should be at least 5MB.

The code below has not been tested, but shows a different approach. The iteratee approach is one where you can create small building blocks and compose them into a pipe of operations.

To make the code compile I added a trait and a few methods

```
trait BucketFilePartUploadTicket
val uploadPart: (Int, Array[Byte]) => Future[BucketFilePartUploadTicket] = ???
val completeUpload: Seq[BucketFilePartUploadTicket] => Future[Unit] = ???
val body: Enumerator[Array[Byte]] = ???
```

Here we create a few parts

```
// Create 5MB chunks
val chunked = {
  val take5MB = Traversable.takeUpTo[Array[Byte]](1024 * 1024 * 5)
  Enumeratee.grouped(take5MB transform Iteratee.consume())
}

// Add a counter, used as part number later on
val zipWithIndex = Enumeratee.scanLeft[Array[Byte]](0 -> Array.empty[Byte]) {
  case ((counter, _), bytes) => (counter + 1) -> bytes
}

// Map the (Int, Array[Byte]) tuple to a BucketFilePartUploadTicket
val uploadPartTickets = Enumeratee.mapM[(Int, Array[Byte])](uploadPart.tupled)

// Construct the pipe to connect to the enumerator
// the ><> operator is an alias for compose, it is more intuitive because of 
// it's arrow like structure
val pipe = chunked ><> zipWithIndex ><> uploadPartTickets

// Create a consumer that ends by finishing the upload
val consumeAndComplete = 
  Iteratee.getChunks[BucketFilePartUploadTicket] mapM completeUpload
```

Running it is done by simply connecting the parts

```
// This is the result, a Future[Unit]
val result = body through pipe run consumeAndComplete
```

Note that I did not test any code and might have made some mistakes in my approach. This however shows a different way of dealing with the problem and should probably help you to find a good solution.

Note that this approach waits for one part to complete upload before it takes on the next part. If the connection from your server to amazon is slower than the connection from the browser to you server this mechanism will slow the input.

You could take another approach where you do not wait for the `Future` of the part upload to complete. This would result in another step where you use `Future.sequence` to convert the sequence of upload futures into a single future containing a sequence of the results. The result would be a mechanism sending a part to amazon as soon as you have enough data.

Comment: There are always multiple problems with my code. What else is new? But it is certainly true the chunks are not 5MB in all cases, so that is an issue. Still, I'll try your ideas and see what I can do.